# iOS SimplePing gives incorrect result at times

Tags: ios, vpn, ping

To sign in and access various functions of our iOS app, the user needs to be connected to our VPN network from their iOS devices. The webservices that the app calls are also only accessible over VPN. In order to determine if the user is running the app over VPN (online mode) or if the user is running the app outside of VPN (offline), we are using Apple's SimplePing class helper https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper. We pass the host name of our web services to make the ping call. If it succeeds, we conclude user is on VPN. If the ping fails, we conclude the user is not on VPN and give him a message saying he needs to connect to VPN.

The issue we are seeing is that sometimes we get a ping failure even if the user is on VPN and this results in the user getting a message that he lacks connectivity. If the user tries some action again, the call succeeds.

We are not sure of what causes the pings to fail intermittently and succeed again when tried in a few seconds. Has anyone experienced this kind of an issue? What could be the possible cause and resolution? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I have looked into the `SimplePingHelper` class, I noticed that there is 1 second timeout, is that too short for you ?

Comment: thanks. I will try increasing the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

We use SimplePing and I noticed that sometimes it fails to resolve the hostname (in `-(void)hostResolutionDone`) even before it gets to the actual ping.  I haven't yet figured out why but my workaround was to stop/restart the ping service.  The host resolution failure happens infrequently so it usually corrects itself the second go around.